# synchronized, mutually dependent concurrent tasks

Tags: asynchronous, ocaml

I searched for a little while and found nothing obvious in Async or Lwt.

Basically, I have a (long running) task that normally would write its output in one large file, e.g.:

```
let rec foo n = if n < 0 then 0 else (store_result n ; foo (n-1))
```

Now I want to synchronize this computation with a client.

The client should be able to signal the next synchronization point, i.e.:

```
let rec foo sync n = if n < 0 then 0 else (if n = sync then let sync' = store_result n in foo sync' (n-1) else foo sync (n-1))
```

So `store_result` would send `n` to the client and then wait for `sync'`. The client on the other hand would have to send `sync'` and then wait for the corresponding `n`.

This process should be **repeated** until the computation is finished. I.e. the client could send synchronisation points 90, 50, 10, 9, ... and get the result at every step.

I am a little bit unfamiliar with asynchroneous computation, but I assume there is an elegant way to implement the whole thing. Unfortunately, I can't search for it, because I don't know its name ;).

So, what would be the most elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is just simple `bind` and `return` (in case of async).

Basically, I guess if your `foo` gets to `sync`, it can only carry on after it gets `new sync` from client, right?

So `bind defer todo` in async let you do this that you say once defer is done by async scheduler, let's plan todo.

```
open Async.Std

let store_result n = Deferred.return (n/2)

let rec foo sync n = 
  if n < 0 then Deferred.return 0 
  else 
    (if n = sync then 
    Deferred.bind (store_result n) (fun sync' -> foo sync' (n-1))
     else 
    foo sync (n-1))
```

I suggest you read https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/concurrent-programming-with-async.html

Comment: Maybe I was not detailed enough. I need repeated synchronization. So store_result should yield something like a recursive tuple (first element of int, second of tuple type).

Comment: @choeger yes, it will be repeated.

Comment: @choeger can you tell me which part you want to repeat?

Comment: I want the client to say "Hey, I need the result for n = 90", the process to compute up to that value, send it and then wait for the next synchronisation point.
Unfortunately, I cannot put this (the sync points) into a deferred value, as they might as well be user input. At least that is not what my understanding of Deferreds is.
I would require some kind of "deferred loop" that blocks on user input for that and I dont see how I can use a recursive deferred (taking the process output)

Comment: I think what you need to refine is the communication with client inside `store_result`. For example, `store_result` may send a message to client over network and wait for the next `sync'`, it won't continue (may not necessarily block because of async) until it gets a `sync'`. it is not important for client to be user input or else, it is important client finally return a value.

Comment: @choeger I guess you really read that chapter, otherwise, it is hard

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work equally well with Lwt and Async.

```
let perform_task init n sync =
  let rec loop data n =
    let data = do_computation data in
    if n < 0 then return 0 else
    if n <> sync
    then loop data (n-1)
    else
      store_result data >>=
      fun () -> loop data (n-1) in
  loop init n
```

I assume, that computation is called synchronously, and that you need to perform it `n` times. On a sync points, the `store_result` is called, that creates a deferred task, that is bound with a thunk `fun () -> loop data (n-1)`. This thunk will be called as soon, as `store_result` is finished.

Please note, that `loop` finishes when `n` becomes negative returning a zero with a function named `return`. Since you're relying on a deferred computations in your function the result of the whole function becomes deferred too.

Yet another note: you need to `open Lwt` or `Async.Std` in order to get access to `return` function and `>>=` operator. The later is a synonym to a `bind` function.